# Is it possible to have some ListView rows with switches, checkboxes?

Tags: android, listview

Is it possible to have some listview rows have a checkbox, or a switch and others to nothing just a title and remain clickable.

I am trying to a do a listview that has a few different settings.

1. First - Checkbox
2. second - Switch
3. Third - Just list.

I know I could do them as separate buttons I would like to have them filled from the same array if possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible using custom design of listview.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layouts-for-each-row

Answer (score 1):

**YES Definately Its possible...**

**1.** Create a custom `layout` for `ListView` or `RecyclerView` `row` item with `CheckBox`, `Switch`, `TextView` or other `views` as per your requirement.

**2.** Create a custom `adapter` extending from `ArrayAdapter`, `BaseAdapter` or `RecyclerView.Adapter` to populate list data to your custom `layout`.

**3.** In `getView()` or `onBindViewHolder()` method, set data to your views and add required `OnClick` or `OnCheckedChange` listener to your Views.

**Here are some tutorial link:**

1. [Android Custom ListView with CheckBox](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)
2. [Android RecyclerView with CheckBox](http://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html)
3. [ListView with CheckBox using custom Adapter class](http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/10/list-view-with-check-box-using-custom.html)
4. [Android ListView with Checkboxes](http://techlovejump.com/android-listview-with-checkbox/)
5. [Android Custom ListView with Image and Text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Hope this will help~